# Shiny inbuilt programs are throwing error

Tags: r, shiny, data-analysis

I am trying to run inbuilt programs(examples) using shiny(through runExample() method) and getting the following error.

> Error in output$DynamicAssets <- renderUI({ argument "output" is missing, with no default

This error occurs with other programs too.
for an instance, this is the code to capture the details being entered by the user:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Enter Personal Details"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(("Enter the personal Details"),
                 textInput("name","Enter your name", ""),
                 textInput("age","Enter your age","")
                 ),
    mainPanel(("Your Entered information is : "),
                textOutput("myname"),
                textOutput("myage")
              )
    )
  )
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(
  function(input,output){
    output$myname= renderText(input$name)
    output$myage=renderText(input$age)

  }
)
```

Still its showing the same error...
edited: Output-> output

Comment: If understood correctly, you try to run examples? Correct way to run them is: `library(shiny)  runExample("01_hello")`

Comment: ya that's correct  I am trying to run examples, Yes i have added library but still I am getting an unresponsive web display(with grey window, which is usually the case when app is being terminated) along with the error as already mentioned.. @MikaelJumppanen

Comment: don't use capital leter in `Output$myname` and try `output$myname <- renderText(input$name)`

Comment: started with it only, but no luck... @MikaelJumppanen
and examples are unresponsive as well :/

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myname <- renderText(input$name)
  output$myage <- renderText(input$age)


}

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Enter Personal Details"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(("Enter the personal Details"),
                               textInput("name", "Enter your name", ""),
                               textInput("age", "Enter your age", "")
                  ),
                  mainPanel(("Your Entered information is : "),
                            textOutput("myname"),
                            textOutput("myage")
                  )
                ))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If it is not working problem is somewhere else than in a code.